# Call multiple function after dynamic time distance using cron

Tags: cron, drupal-7

I have one problems, but i can't understand how to describe you for solve my problems. I m tying to understand you.

I have create a custom module that create a form and has some fields like id,url,dom pattern,time,schedule.

** After submit 2 item by using this form, it store all data to my database table.

```
pattern_store_table

id | url                       | pattern       | time       schedule
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | http://example.com/page1  | #div_1234 h2  | 1460864020 | 60
2  | http://example.com/page2  | #div_4567 h2  | 1465311839 | 30
```

Then I have created some function for collect data from other websites using third party dom parsing script, based on there websites url and Html Dom pattern. Then, i store this data as my drupal node.

And i create a list page based on "pattern_store_table" table data items. And create a function for call my scrap functionality.

So, when i hit "//example.com/scrap/id/1" into my browser, it scrap title from "http://example.com/page1" and store as my drupal node, and when i hit "//example.com/scrap/id/2" into my browser, it scrap title from "http://example.com/page2" and store as my drupal node.

**My Problem is:**

I don't want to hit always "//example.com/scrap/id/1" into browser. I want to create a function that call "//example.com/scrap/id/1" automatically every "schedule" fields timewise like "60 (for id 1)", "30 (for id 2)" then collect and store data into my database.

```
I listen about CRON, but i don't know how can i use it with my custom module.
```

Anybody please help me to automate this system step by step?

Sorry for my bad english. :(

Comment: please anybody help...

Comment: hey man, nobody can't help?